# In F#, what is difference between two generic type constraint representations

Tags: generics, f#, type-constraints

I am using Rx for a scheduling project. One of the methods looks like:

```
let strike (scheduler: 'a when 'a :> IScheduler option) strikeTime source =
    match strikeTime with
    | StrikeOnceAt due -> strikeOnce scheduler (Choice1Of2 due) source
    | StrikeOnceAfter delay -> strikeOnce scheduler (Choice2Of2 delay) source
    | StrikeEvery (period, last) -> strikeEvery scheduler period last source
```

When testing, I am using a `HistoricalScheduler`, which, of course, derives from `IScheduler`.

```
let ``Repeater strikes at given rate per minute`` rpm =
    let sched = new HistoricalScheduler(DateTimeOffset.Now)
    let rate = rpm |> int64 |> Min |> toRate

    let repeat = Repeater.StrikeEvery (rate, None)
    use actual = Repeater.strike (Some sched) repeat source
```

Instead of casting `sched :> IScheduler` in the calling code, I'm hoping to use type constraints like shown above.

I am unsure whether to represent the constraint as...

`(scheduler: 'a option when 'a :> IScheduler)` -or- 
`(scheduler: 'a when 'a :> IScheduler option)`

Is this just preference? Is there a reason to choose one way over the other?

Comment: I doubt very much that the latter variant actually works. Does it for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deciding between

> `(scheduler: 'a option when 'a :> IScheduler)` -or-
>
> `(scheduler: 'a when 'a :> IScheduler option)`,

the compiler will tell you that the first variant resolves as

`(scheduler: #IScheduler option)`

while the second should generate a warning that it has been constrained to

`(scheduler: IScheduler option)`.

Therefore your first variant does actually what you want it to do. The `#` notation is called [flexible type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types).

Comment: I was wondering what the purpose of hash (#) notation was all about.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Don't know why they call it "flexable types", it is an implicit Interface caster, whereas otherwise in F#, all interface usage is explicit with a cast to the interface.